# How To Reverse The Order Of LinkedHashMap Elements In Scala

Tags: scala, collections, linkedhashmap

Is there any elegant way to reverse the elements' order of LinkedHashMap in Scala?

For instance, I have a LinkedHashMap[Integer, String] like:

```
[1, "one"]
[2, "two"]
[3, "three"]
```

What is the best way to get a LinkedHashMap[Integer, String] like:

```
[3, "three"]
[2, "two"]
[1, "one"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

val linked = LinkedHashMap(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")

val reversed = LinkedHashMap(linked.toSeq.reverse: _*)
// reversed: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, String] = Map(3 -> three, 2 -> two, 1 -> one)
```

Comment: Thank you. Discovered the '_*' for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
val reverse = for ((key, value) <- map) yield (value, key)
```

Note that this will not update the old `LinkedHashMap`, but will return a new one.

Comment: This reverses the keys and values; it doesn't reverse the order of the elements, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: indeed, I am looking for how to reverse the order of the entries of the map